# Excel 365 - Crash when Filtering ADODB.RecordSet via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, office365, adodb, excel-365

I have some Excel 2013 & Excel 2017 spreadsheets that make extensive use of VBA, downloading and processing data from Oracle.  We have recently migrated to Office 365 (64 bit), so I am having to update these spreadsheets to work in the new environment.  Most of the migration has worked fine... but I am consistently getting a crash when executing some code that applies a filter to a recordset.

This code works perfectly in Excel 2017 (32 bit).

```
Dim thisContractID As Long
While outputSheet.Range("CONTRACT_LIST").Cells(2, col).value <> 0
    thisContractID = outputSheet.Range("CONTRACT_LIST").Cells(2, col).value
    quantityData.Filter = "SALES_CONTRACT_ID=" & thisContractID     '<= Crash here.  ThisContractID is a Long, and value exists in the recordset.
    While Not quantityData.EOF
        earliestDate = quantityData![EFFECTIVE_FROM]
        latestDate = quantityData![EFFECTIVE_TO]
        For thisDate = startDate To endDate
            If thisDate >= earliestDate And thisDate <= latestDate Then
                dateOffset = thisDate - startDate + 4
                outputSheet.Range("CONTRACT_LIST").Cells(1, col).Offset(dateOffset, 0).value = quantityData![DAILY_QUANTITY_GJ]
                outputSheet.Range("CONTRACT_LIST").Cells(1, col).Offset(dateOffset, 11).value = quantityData![DAILY_MAX_GJ]
            End If
        Next thisDate
        quantityData.MoveNext
    Wend
    col = col + 1
Wend
```

In the locals window, I can see that the recordset has 5 fields (expected), "SALES_CONTRACT_ID" is the first field, with the adVarNumeric type.  Not sure what other info to provide - I use an adOpenStatic cursor and an adLockReadOnly lock.

What I've tried:

- Setting the thisContractID as a LongLong.
- Adding quantityData.MoveFirst before applying the filter.
- Changing the filter to  filter = """SALES_CONTRACT_ID=" & thisContractID & """" (evaluates to "SALES_CONTRACT_ID=723" on the first iteration. => Runtime error '3001'
- Changing the filter to filter = "SALES_CONTRACT_ID='" & thisContractID & "'" (evaluates to SALES_CONTRAACT_ID='723' on the first iteration; still crashes.
- Changing library reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library (was the 6.1 library)

I'm not sure what else to try!  Any help appreciated.

Comment: What exactly does "getting a crash" look like?

Comment: A pause, and then Excel simply disappears.  Get an application crash log in windows event viewer:  _Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.12527.21236, time stamp: 0x5f8262ff
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.17134.1425, time stamp: 0x4c780f2c_

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the Filter:

```
While Not quantityData.EOF
    If quantityData![SALES_CONTRACT_ID] = thisContractID Then  '<-- new
    earliestDate = quantityData![EFFECTIVE_FROM]
    latestDate = quantityData![EFFECTIVE_TO]
    For thisDate = startDate To endDate
        If thisDate >= earliestDate And thisDate <= latestDate Then
            dateOffset = thisDate - startDate + 4
            outputSheet.Range("CONTRACT_LIST").Cells(1, col).Offset(dateOffset, 0).value = quantityData![DAILY_QUANTITY_GJ]
            outputSheet.Range("CONTRACT_LIST").Cells(1, col).Offset(dateOffset, 11).value = quantityData![DAILY_MAX_GJ]
        End If
    Next thisDate
    End If   '<-- new
    quantityData.MoveNext
```

Or use a WHERE clause and issue multiple SQL queries instead of filtering a large recordset.

**UPDATE:**

Looks like a bug with VBA and O365: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_win10-mso_365hp/ms-access-crashes-when-filtering-a-table-or-select/f3fac17c-af3a-45aa-b8f6-46585e6413a5

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I could insert the If / End If, and I'll do that if I can't get it to work as it should.  It is not a large recordset (in this particular case) - only 5 records of 5 fields.  So I don't think the crash is related to the recordset size.

Comment: Ah - thanks for the link to the bug report.  I'd done a bit of googling, but hadn't come across that.  I note a post on Page 5 from Microsoft saying it had been fixed.  People there are on build 12430(ish); I'm on 12527.